Access error when push to or cloning a repository in gitea server
I made a gitea server on Ubuntu and behind nginx. When I tried to clone each repository on this server or push it to it, I got the error below.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitea.sarir.tech/Management-Software/test.git/': Maximum 
(20) redirects followed

